# How can show and hide options from a reactive Button?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

I don't know exactly how to deal with this.

I have three buttons and I want that when the user select one of the buttons a checkbox appears with options and when the user changes the button the checkbox with the options change.

Example

```
actionButton("casos_button", "Casos", class = "btn-primary "),
actionButton("muertes_button", "Muertes", class = "btn-primary "),
actionButton("hospitalizados", "Hospitalizados", class = "btn-primary "),
```

If the user select the first button a check box appears with 3 options and if he select the second button then the options that correspond to the first button disappear and the checkbox options appear for the second button.

button 1
button 2
button 3

If the user select button 1 then a checkbox with 3 options appears
If the user select button 2 then a checkbox with 4 options appears
If the user select button 3 then a checkbox with 2 options appears

I am a noob with shiny and I really appreciate your helo

Comment: This link should help you.  (https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.3/observeEvent.html)  @coding

Comment: Thank you! But they are rendering a data Table how can I render a checkbox group options?

Comment: Try this, as I understood you want to show and hide options based on the user's decision. This example adds an action button you will add a checkbox instead of it.
`shinyApp(ui = basicPage(actionButton("go", "Go")),server = function(input, output, session){observeEvent(input$go,{insertUI("#go", "afterEnd",actionButton("dynamic", "click to remove"))
observeEvent(input$dynamic, {removeUI("#dynamic")}, ignoreInit = TRUE, once = TRUE)})})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses `shinyjs` to first hide the `checkboxGroupInput`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  actionButton("button_1", "First Options"),
  actionButton("button_2", "Second Options"),
  hidden(checkboxGroupInput("options", "select the options", c("A", "B")))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$button_1, {
    show("options")
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                             "options",
                             choices = c("A", "B"))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$button_2, {
    show("options")
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                             "options",
                             choices = c("C", "D"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you